# Chart.js Bar charts have always the value of 1 whyle i took variables

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and have a question to Chart.js implementation. I've got several variables out of my database which I Transfer like this to js code:

```
var e10_js = <?php echo $e10_durchschnitt_dec; ?>;
```

the bar Chart Code is:

```
    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {

    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Diesel","E5","E10","BLA","BLI","BLUB"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Population (millions)",
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#3cba9f","#3cba9f","#3cba9f"],
          data: [diesel_js,e5_js,e10_js,diesel_max_js,e5_max_js,e5_js]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      legend: { display: false },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
      }
    }
});
```

if i Change one variable to a normal number like that:

```
data: [diesel_js,e5_js,e10_js,diesel_max_js,e5_max_js,2]
```

every bar shows up normally like they should. If I don't do this and only my variable controls the bars, every bar gets a value of 1.

I really don't know why it doesn't work... Hopefully, someone can help a newbie--
thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `Number(<?php echo $e10_durchschnitt_dec; ?>);`

Also, are you sure that PHP variable is not null?